# Удаление из строки всех цифр с помощью replace

Tags: javascript

Нужно удалить из строчки все цифры. Использую

```
urlall=url.replace(/[^a-z]/, '');
```

но удаляет лишь один символ (цифру), подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Флаги](http://learn.javascript.ru/flags)

```
url.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '')
```

Comment: url.replace(/[^a-z]/g, '') только на 5символов

Answer (score 3):

Если все *цифры*, тогда, наверное, `url.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')` :)

Comment: `/\d/` не, не слышал